# Questions for Epistula XCVII (Trajan to Pliny)

Tags: grammar-identification

> Si deferantur et arguantur, puniendi sunt, ita tamen ut qui negaverit 'se Christianum esse' idque re ipsa manifestum fecerit, id est supplicando dis nostris, quamvis suspectus in praeteritum, veniam ex paenitentia impetret.

(unmacronized)

- Why the protasis of ***si*** is *subj.* (***deferantur et arguantur***), but the apodosis is *ind.* (***puniendi sunt***)? Is it because the apodosis is future periphrastic? (*I found this case in Allen & Greenough's: 517.c, but I am not sure*)
- What is the structure from ***qui negaverit...***? If ***qui negaverit (et) fecerit*** (as I guess) is the subject (*he who ...*), which is the corresponding verb?
- Why is it ***in praeteritum*** instead of ***in praeterito***?

Answer (score 3):

- About the structure *qui negaverit*: I agree it seems to be the subject. The corresponding verb is apparently the last word in this passage: *impetret*. i.e., "he who denies... will obtain pardon." (*veniam impetret*)
- About *in praeteritum*: We can compare it to *in posterum* and *in futurum* to mean "in the future" which is the natural way to go. Why *in futurum* and not *in futuro*? Well, maybe that's another question. Another possibility I find less probable is that maybe the idea is not that he was suspected *in/during* the past, but rather that he is currently suspected *on account of* the past; or more particularly a specific action in the past that he committed. [According to L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=suscipio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), *suscipio* can have in+acc. But the examples given there are all in the pattern of *suscipere is se alqiud*, so it is not quite the same thing. maybe a simple ablative without in would have the same function; So, though I could not find a good example, I think the probable idea that *suspectus in praeteritum* means something along the lines that he is charged for his past action.
- about the subj of *deferantur et arguantur* vs. the indicative *puniendi sunt*: I'm afraid I don't have an answer, but just wanted to note that the words before the *si* clause are *"Conquirendi non sunt"*.